# What do the numbered stickers on breakers in my service panel mean?

Tags: electrical-panel

I just bought a house and the breakers in the panel are covered in these numbered stickers. What do these signify?

[image]

Some internal shots behind the cover.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Odd.  Only thing I think of is those numbers were to be place on/near outlets/lights so you knew which breaker to turn off.  Or paid stickers from a store.

Comment: @isherwood I know I left a comment, but I can't see it now. I only left as a comment since there is really no way to tell why the labels are there.

Comment: Looks like the community removed it. It should be common knowledge that answers (even guesses) don't belong there. Comments are for gaining clarity about a question or answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've known people to write breaker numbers on the back of switch/outlet cover plates, for convenient reference. Maybe someone did something similar with these cable-numbering stickers. Or maybe there's a reference table somewhere. Seems a sloppy solution, but I haven't seen many pretty solutions.

I'd have used the numbers embossed into the breaker box, at least on the box end of things, unless I was moving a breaker to a new location. "Old number 14")

Comment: I suppose it must have been done with a partially used sheet of number stickers, given the odd mish-mash of numbers.

Comment: Everyone who uses those stickers at all has a pile of leftovers looking for an excuse to be put to work. And it's possible the numbers are more rational in terms of where they are in the building than where they are in the breaker box. But this is a sloppy enough labelling job that I suspect it was someone's ad-hoc solution to a specific problem, and the intent was to improve it later when enough Round Tuits had accumulated.

Comment: I could actually use a sheet or three of those at this point. I have a pile of XLR cables that ought to get sorted by size and labelled so one can be told from another. (And tested, and labelled with my color code, and...) When my own Round Tuits pile up high enough.

Comment: eh, just get a label printer. They even have colour label tape :D

Comment: Have one. Not as durable.

Comment: Heat shrink (clear) over it.

Comment: Not practical when XLR connectors already attached.  Yeah, tape or something can be made to work and I may wind up doing that, but. (And we're digressing )

Answer (score 1):

These look like wire labels. Used during install so electrician can keep track of which wire/outlet/switch goes to which breaker. Likely if you opened up an outlet and started to pull the heavy wire out, you would see a corresponding label that looks exactly like these.